# Expression for doing something too much in a very specific way

Tags: idiom-request

We have an expression in Hungarian that literally translates to "falling off at the other side of the horse" meaning approaching something in a single way without thinking of any other approach.

An example:

> Prefer reactive programming over iterative but you should "not fall on the other side of the horse".

The above sentence means you should generally use reactive programming to solve the task, but you should not use it where it doesn't make any sense to do it.

Is there any similar idiom/expression in English for this?

Comment: Not directly interchangeable, but a related idiom is "when all you have is a hammer, everything looks like a nail".

Comment: Related is the expression to beware of **the law of unintended consequences**, meaning that you fail to foresee what your decision (or actions) will lead to.

Comment: One of the simplest and most common (and *versatile*) "single-word" verbs for this context (and many similar) is *...but don't **overdo** it.* If you only want to remember one really easy word, that's your best best. But there are literally *hundreds* of terms that could be used, so I think the question is essentially POB.

Comment: Classic FumbleFingers comment. "I think this question should be closed (and therefore doesn't deserve to be answered). Here's my answer (in a comment)."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A very common expression for this is *to go overboard*.

> Prefer reactive programming over iterative, but don't go overboard.

Comment: This is a good one. Thanks!